# Simple Basic Python compare

Tags: python, types, numbers, compare

I found this interesting question when I was doing homework
we know, `47.36/1.6**2 == 18.5`

but when I try to run the following code, it gives me a False(should be true)

print `47.36/1.6**2 == 18.5`

Do anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 4):

You're probably getting an answer like 18.49999999999, which is not *exactly* equal to 18.5.

As always, the relevant reference for this is [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> 47.36/1.6**2
18.499999999999996
```

[See this page on Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Here is how you can calculate this to exactly `18.5` without using any rounding or "close enough" behavior by using the [decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('47.36') / Decimal('1.6')**2 == Decimal('18.5')
True
>>> float(Decimal('47.36') / Decimal('1.6')**2) == 18.5
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: IEEE 754 floating point can't exactly represent fractions where the denominator isn't a power of two, like 1/4, 1/16, 1/256, etc. You can get awfully close, given enough digits, but never quite exactly there.

You compare floating point numbers by defining "equals" as "within a certain delta". You could write something like:

```
def almost_equals(a, b, delta=0.0005):
    return abs(a - b) <= delta
```

and then test for "probably equal" with:

```
>>> almost_equals(47.36/1.6**2, 18.5)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid checking for exact equality when comparing two floats.  Instead take the difference and see if it is smaller than a value you consider close to zero.

(47.36/1.6**2 - 18.5) < 0.00000000001

will be

True

Answer (score 1):

As others have said:

```
>>> 47.36/1.6**2
18.499999999999996
```

But, this is NOT due to a floating-point arithmetic problem as far as I can tell.  Even if you use decimal math by wrapping the operands in `Decimal()` (after `from decimal import Decimal`) you will still get `Decimal('18.49999999999999772404279952')` as the answer.

It's possible I'm using `Decimal()` wrong here and my result also has some sort of floating point error; however, if I'm correct, that expression flat out does not equal `18.5`, no matter what kind of math you use.

**Edit:** As Greg points out in the comments, the problem with my approach here is that Decimal(1.6) will just convert the float representation of 1.6, inaccuracies intact, into a Decimal. This gives the correct answer:

```
>>> Decimal('47.36') / Decimal('1.6')**2
Decimal('18.5')
```

Better still would be to use the [fractions](http://docs.python.org/library/fractions.html) module as suggested by Kirk.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha confirms using rational arithmetic that the answer is exactly 18.5: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=47.36%2F1.6%2A%2A2

Comment: Look at [fractions](http://docs.python.org/library/fractions.html) instead. Decimal doesn't handle rational numbers.

Comment: You're right, for some reason `>>> Decimal(1.6)**2` `Decimal('2.560000000000000284217094304')` even though 1.6 * 1.6 clearly equals 2.56 on the nose.

Comment: @AndrewGorcester: That's probably due to the imprecision of 1.6 as a double. Try `Decimal(16) / Decimal(10)` and see what you get.

Comment: Passing the numbers into `Decimal` as strings also avoids the float representation issues - `Decimal('47.36')/Decimal('1.6') ** 2` gives `Decimal('18.5')`.

Comment: @lvc amended the revised answer to include this easier method, thanks!

Answer (score -3):

47.36/1.6**2 return integer. So 47.36/1.6**2 would be 18, which is not equal to 18.5.

**Edit**

Sorry about that, actually it is being stored as 18.499999.
You should do this

`import numpy as np

print np.around((47.36/1.6**2), decimals=1) == 18.5`

This would return True.

Comment: Nothing against numpy and it's a brilliant piece of work, but that's a pretty huge dependency to pull in just to compare a couple of floats.

Comment: yeah, you are right. Unless your are doing mathematical intensive program, it would be a burden to import it.